# Неверный подсчет при нажатии на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, html

> Не правильно считает значения при нажатии на чекбокс:сумму подсчитывает верно, при нажатии на чекбокс когда выбраны все 3 выпадающих списка - не правильный выдает ответ.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;

$('select').each(function() {

sum += parseInt($(this).val());
});
var prinprice1 = 0;

//покраска по размерам взяли значения из текста селекта
  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked'))

{if  (($('#shirina').val() == "0") || ($('#dlina').val() == "0") || ($('#visota').val() == "0")) sum += 2500; prinprice1 += 2500;

  switch ($('#shirina option:selected').text())
  {
    case "900" : sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break;
    case "1000": sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break; 
    case "1100": sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 
    }
   switch ($('#dlina option:selected').text())
  {
    case "1900" : sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break;
    case "2000" : sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 
    case "2100" : sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 
 }
  switch ($('#visota option:selected').text())
  {
    case "1600" : sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break;
    case "1700" : sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 
    case "1800" : sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 
 }

//вывод на чекбокс покраска
  $('#price1').html(prinprice1); 
} 

//итоговая цена
  $('#final_price').html(sum);

}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<h2>Заказать кровать чердак</h2>
<fieldset class="form_zakaz_border">
<legend>Основные параметры</legend>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <p><select name="model_krovat" id="model">
      <option  selected="selected" value="6300">Белава</option>
        <option  value="6300">Купе</option>
        <option  value="7000">Чердак</option>
        <option  value="8000">Пирамидка</option>
        </select></p>
    </td>
  <td><select name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option   value="0" selected="selected">800</option>
  <option   value="500">900</option>
  <option   value="1000">1000</option>
  <option   value="1000">1100</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td><select name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1700</option>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">1800</option>
  <option value="500">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
  <option value="1000">2100</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td><select name="visota_krovat" id="visota">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">1500</option>
    <option value="500">1600</option>
    <option value="1000">1700</option>
    <option value="1000">1800</option>
   </select>
  </td>
<td>
</tr>
<label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски 
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" /> 
<span id="price1">2500</span> Руб.<br />

Стоимость:  <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3sbtzcwa/6/

Comment: Приведите хоть пример какой ответ ожидаете и какой ответ выводится на каких входных данных. И лучше сделайте так чтобы значение у чекбокса диамически менялось вместе со стоимостью, а то поведение выглядит неочевидным.

Comment: выбираем 1 выпадающии список:1100,стоимость=7300(6300+1000) и нажимаем чекбокс 2700(2500+200) итого 7300+2700=10000.это верно,выбираем 2 вып.список 2100, стоимость=10000+1000+200=11200 правильно. выбираем 3 выпадающии список любое 1800 стоимость 9900,почему-то вычитает

Comment: динамически что бы менялось на чекбоксе, это я не смогла сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в скрипте какой-то беспорядок, попробовал порефакторить, проверьте как считает теперь.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;

  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  var prinprice1 = 2500;

  switch ($('#shirina option:selected').text()) {
    case "900":
      prinprice1 += 100;
      break;
    case "1000":
      prinprice1 += 100;
      break;
    case "1100":
      prinprice1 += 200;
      break;
  }
  switch ($('#dlina option:selected').text()) {
    case "1900":
      prinprice1 += 100;
      break;
    case "2000":
      prinprice1 += 200;
      break;
    case "2100":
      prinprice1 += 200;
      break;
  }
  switch ($('#visota option:selected').text()) {
    case "1600":
      prinprice1 += 100;
      break;
    case "1700":
      prinprice1 += 200;
      break;
    case "1800":
      prinprice1 += 200;
      break;
  }

  //вывод на чекбокс покраска
  $('#price1').html(prinprice1);
  //покраска по размерам взяли значения из текста селекта
  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked')) sum += prinprice1;
  //итоговая цена
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<h2>Заказать кровать чердак</h2>
<fieldset class="form_zakaz_border">
  <legend>Основные параметры</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><select name="model_krovat" id="model">
      <option  selected="selected" value="6300">Белава</option>
        <option  value="6300">Купе</option>
        <option  value="7000">Чердак</option>
        <option  value="8000">Пирамидка</option>
        </select></p>
      </td>
      <td><select name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option   value="0" selected="selected">800</option>
  <option   value="500">900</option>
  <option   value="1000">1000</option>
  <option   value="1000">1100</option>
  </select>
      </td>
      <td><select name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1700</option>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">1800</option>
  <option value="500">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
  <option value="1000">2100</option>
  </select>
      </td>
      <td><select name="visota_krovat" id="visota">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">1500</option>
    <option value="500">1600</option>
    <option value="1000">1700</option>
    <option value="1000">1800</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски 
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" /> 
<span id="price1">2500</span> Руб.<br />

Стоимость:  <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
```

Comment: все верно считает!спасибо большое!!!

Comment: когда просто нужно к сумме прибавить число при нажатии на чекбокс:  if ($("#bort").is(':checked')) sum += 1400;  не работает,что-то не так пишу?

Comment: на первый взгляд всё так, может добавлете уже после заполнения результата?

Comment: пишу до вывода результата

Comment: тогда причина может быть любой, соберите минимальный! (например чтобы был только 1 чекбокс и зона вывода, без всех ваших селектов и прочих контролов) на котором можно воспроизвести проблему, а то ваши примеры уже слишком большие. возможно при составлении минимального примера сами найдете ошибку и вопрос отпадет.

Comment: хорошо,попробую

Comment: Оказывается Bort с большои написано в  id="Bort",моя невнимательность.Теперь все работает!)))

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуиста,  если задать input text "Введите количество" что бы подсчитать  количество * сумму. Как это прописать в этом коде?

Comment: не понял вопрос

Comment: чтобы введенное число через страницу, умножалось на сумму. Допустим цена 6300 на странице, вводим 10 шт выводится 630000